# Does Google Analytics consider a transition from one website to be an exit?

Tags: google-analytics, exit-pages

Consider an example where I am browsing through `facebook.com`. There I saw a `medium blog` shared by my friend and I click on it to open. Now since Facebook opens that on a new tab, we technically didn't exit from it but what if that blog opens up in the same tab. Will it be considered to be an `exit` from `facebook.com`?

What if after reading the blog, I press back button on browser and land back again on `facebook.com`?

Comment: Yes. These are two different sites as any search engine sees it.

Comment: Are the properties linked in Google Analytics?

Comment: @StephenOstermiller I am sorry but I didn't understand your statement completely. I have started recently learning about google analytics and so have a just basic understanding of the terms and usages. Please elaborate a bit.

Comment: I guess I meant do they have cross-domain tracking: https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/1034342?hl=en

Comment: This is an exact duplicate of a question you asked earlier that was put on hold as unclear. Rather than just asking it again, please provide more details to clarify it.